# Update Node Problematically is not working fine

Tags: 7, hooks

I am using Drupal-6 . I am trying to update single field using following code.

```
    $nodnew->id=14;
    $nodenew->field_site_url[$array_id]['value']=$website_url; 
   $nodenew->revision=1; 
   $nodenew->changed = $node->created; 
   $nodenew->comment = 0; 
   $nodenew->type ='product';
   node_save($nodenew);
```

It updates field_site_url sucessfully. But it also changes other fields to blank. 
like title, body etc. i want to add only field_site_url.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't just pick and choose which bit of a node to save, you either save the whole thing or nothing at all when using `node_save()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to load node with its id :

```
   $nodenew = node_load(14); // load the complete node
```

So when you use node_save() all other field values that was previously stored in database will automatically get loaded. Then only thing remains is the field you want to update.

```
   $nodenew->field_site_url[$array_id]['value']=$website_url; 
   $nodenew->revision=1;
   $nodenew->created = time();
   $nodenew->changed = $nodenew->created; 
   $nodenew->comment = 0; 
   $nodenew->type ='product';
   node_save($nodenew);
```